# display Grouping json list into ionic list

Tags: json, ionic2

I have a json object , i want to display it into an ionic list by grouping  objects by villearrive , i have tried the code below

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {VoitureService} from '../../providers/voitureservice';
import {TicketService} from '../../providers/ticket-service';
/*
  Generated class for the Listevoiture page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-listevoiture',
  templateUrl: 'listevoiture.html',
  providers:[VoitureService]
})
export class ListevoiturePage {
 
  itemsFile:any;
   

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private alert :AlertController,public alertCtrl: AlertController, public voitureservice:VoitureService) {
   
    this.RetournerdVoituresEnstation();
  }


   
      RetournerdVoituresEnstation(){

          this.voitureservice.getDetailsVilleArrive().subscribe(response => {
          this.itemsFile =response.FileS;
          
          });
        
     }
    

    

}
```

```html
<ion-content>

<ion-item-group *ngFor="let pr of itemsFile">
    
      <ion-item-sliding >
 
    <ion-item >
      
<ion-item-divider  color="danger" >{{pr.villearrive}} </ion-item-divider>
    <h2>{{pr.matricule}}:اللوحة المنجمية</h2>
    <h3>{{pr.marque}}:نوع السيارة</h3>
   <h3>{{pr.climatisation}}:مكيفة</h3>
 <h3>{{pr.nbrplacereserve}}:عدد المقاعد المحجوزة</h3>
  <h3>{{pr.dateenregistrement}}:تاريخ التسجيل</h3>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-item-group>
</ion-content
```

the result obtained looks ike that :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5CJ3.png)

the json file is :
{"FileS":[{"matricule":"126 TN 1368","villearrive":"صفاقس","marque":"Fiat","climatisation":"1","nbrplacereserve":"3","dateenregistrement":"31/03/2017"},{"matricule":"126 TN 1368","villearrive":"صفاقس","marque":"Fiat","climatisation":"1","nbrplacereserve":"3","dateenregistrement":"31/03/2017"},{"matricule":"126 TN 1368","villearrive":"صفاقس","marque":"Fiat","climatisation":"1","nbrplacereserve":"3","dateenregistrement":"31/03/2017"},{"matricule":"126 TN 1368","villearrive":"صفاقس","marque":"Fiat","climatisation":"1","nbrplacereserve":"3","dateenregistrement":"31/03/2017"},{"matricule":"195 TN 3987","villearrive":"صفاقس","marque":"Peugeot","climatisation":"0","nbrplacereserve":"3","dateenregistrement":"31/03/2017"},{"matricule":"103 TN 9865","villearrive":"القيروان","marque":"Fiat","climatisation":"0","nbrplacereserve":"5","dateenregistrement":"31/03/2017"},{"matricule":"103 TN 9865","villearrive":"القيروان","marque":"Fiat","climatisation":"0","nbrplacereserve":"5","dateenregistrement":"31/03/2017"}],"success":1}

Comment: but what's wrong? In the image it looks right

Comment: i would like that items will be grouping by ( villearrive) , the actual problem that , for example villearrive "A" is repeated in the result ( it must appear Only once)